# Add "refresh all connections" functionality

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I have an app which uses the microsoft graph api to get info about an excel file stored in share point. This is what that info looks like:
[graph api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP1Gm.png)
I want to add a button in my app to allow the user to "refresh all connections" of that specific excel file. In other words, I want to resemble this functionality from excel for the web in my app:[excel for the web - refresh all connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyrcO.png)

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found to Refresh session, you can use this API to refresh an existing workbook session, but not sure for all refresh connections.

```
POST /me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/refreshSession
POST /me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/workbook/refreshSession
workbook-session-id: {session-id}
```

Please refer this link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/workbook-refreshsession?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope this helps.